# header() tag not redirecting after submiting form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm almost finishing my first PHP/HTML site, and I'm stacked in this redirect after submiting a HTML Form with 'connect.php'.

I guess there is something going wrong with this 'header()' tag , because the sql post is working fine.

First, the form:

```
<div id="formulario">
    <form action="connect.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="alert('Thank you for your feedback.')">
        <p id="form_title">COMPLETA TUS DATOS Y ENVIA ESTA SOLICITUD <br> A LAS AUTORIDADES</p>

        <label></label>
        <input class="field" name="user_name" type="text" required="required" placeholder="NOMBRE">


        <label></label>
        <input class="field" name="user_last" type="text" required="required" placeholder="APELLIDO">


        <label></label>
        <input class="field" name="pais" type="text" required="required" placeholder="PAIS">

        <label></label> 
        <input class="field" name="user_email" type="email" required="required" placeholder="EMAIL">

        <label></label>
        <input class="field" name="tel" type="number" required="required" placeholder="TELEFONO">


        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">

        <div id="masinfo">
            <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="" alt="" />CLICK AQUI PARA MAS INFO</a>
        </div>

    </form>
```

Now, the 'connect.php' file:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'm9000207_ficlog');
define('DB_USER', 'm9000207_ficlog');
define('DB_PASSWORD','25dutotePE');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

$value1 = $_POST ['user_name'];
$value2 = $_POST ['user_last'];
$value3 = $_POST ['pais'];
$value4 = $_POST ['tel'];
$value5 = $_POST ['user_email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO registros VALUES ('', '$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5')";

if($value1 !=''&& $value2 !=''&& $value3 !=''&& $value4 !=''&& $value5 !=''){
    header("Location: index.html");
}


if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Cant use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error ());
}

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: Which errors are you getting? Also, bear in mind [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Never use that code for production.

Comment: Still needs saying : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: Are sure that you are getting inside the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

You cannot redirect after output has started. Try moving the check taking place in connect.php to before the outputting of the form. Also, it's good practice to immediately exit() after the header() call to prevent output after the call.

Answer (score 0):

Your script probably has some output that you can't see, i.e. whitespace. Get around this by using `ob_start()` at the top of your script to start a buffer, and ob_end_clean() to discard it before your redirect..

```
<?php 
ob_start(); // Begin a buffer

define('DB_NAME', 'm9000207_ficlog');
define('DB_USER', 'm9000207_ficlog');
define('DB_PASSWORD','25dutotePE');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

$value1 = $_POST ['user_name'];
$value2 = $_POST ['user_last'];
$value3 = $_POST ['pais'];
$value4 = $_POST ['tel'];
$value5 = $_POST ['user_email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO registros VALUES ('', '$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5')";

if($value1 !=''&& $value2 !=''&& $value3 !=''&& $value4 !=''&& $value5 !=''){
    ob_end_clean(); // Discard any output
    header("Location: index.html");
    exit; // Good practice
}


if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Cant use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error ());
}



mysql_close();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally:

`if($value1 != '')` is wrong

the right way is: `if($value1 !== '')` or `if(empty($value1))`

but I recmmend the usage of arrays

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i checked outputs (data going to front-end) before de PHP elements, and deleted items below the last header()'s if.

Thanks all of you!. Here is the final code, working:

```html
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'm9000207_ficlog');
define('DB_USER', 'm9000207_ficlog');
define('DB_PASSWORD','25dutotePE');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' .mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

$value1 = $_POST ['user_name'];
$value2 = $_POST ['user_last'];
$value3 = $_POST ['pais'];
$value4 = $_POST ['tel'];
$value5 = $_POST ['user_email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO registros VALUES ('', '$value1', '$value2', '$value3', '$value4', '$value5')";

mysql_close();

if($value1 !=''&& $value2 !=''&& $value3 !=''&& $value4 !=''&& $value5 !=''){
    header("Location: index.html");
 exit();
}


?>
<h2>Gracias!, hemos recibido su firma. Ahora, será redirigido.</h2>
```